# make program that delete all number from text

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, c-strings

i want to make program using pointer that delete all number from text, for example when the input from keyboard is "ab1c9" then the program result "abc" only. so i actually think about using the pointer and overwrite it using the word without number result but it doesnt seem work :/ and im still confuse about when should i use * or not
is this program logic true ?.?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void deldigit(char* str) {
    int count = 0;

    while(*str != '\0') {
        if(*str >= '1' && *str <= '9')
            count++;
        else
            *(str - count) = *str; /* want this *str after increment to overwrite *(str-count) */
        str++;
    }

    *(str - count) = '\0';
    printf("%s", str);
}

int main() {
    char str[100];

    printf("inset word");
    scanf("%s", &str);
    deldigit(str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s",&str)` is a type error: `%s` expects a `char *`; `&str` is a `char (*)[100]`. It's also unsafe (vulnerable to buffer overflows). And don't use `scanf` for user input.

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. Your code can be simplified to: `int main(void) { char *str = "ab1c9"; while (*str != '\0') { str++; } printf("%s", str); return 0; }`

Comment: why cant i use scanf for input? and why str not &str? is it possible to make char *str[100]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rewind `str` after the loop, and you are not deleting zeros in the string, change to something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void deldigit(char *str)
{
    char *res = str;
    int count = 0;

    while (*str != '\0') {
        if (isdigit((unsigned char)*str)) {
            count++;
        } else {
            *(str - count) = *str;
        }
        str++;
    }
    *(str - count) = '\0';
    printf("%s", res);
}

int main(void)
{
    char str[100];
    char *ptr;

    printf("insert word: ");
    if (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)) {
        if ((ptr = strchr(str, '\n'))) {
            *ptr = '\0';
        }
        deldigit(str);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Switched to `fgets` in order to avoid buffer overflows.

Comment: That still suffers from a buffer overflow in `scanf` `%s`. `char` can be a signed type and passing negative numbers to `isdigit` has undefined behavior, so `isdigit(*str)` is a bad idea. You don't need an extra variable if you do the printing in `main`.

Comment: Why the cast to `unsiged char` in the call to `isdigit`?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, read the @ melpomene's comment: _char can be a signed type and passing negative numbers to isdigit has undefined behavior_

Comment: @KeineLust thankyou for reviewing! from your code: i need two pointers into the string that both starting at the first char, is this what you mean rewind str? then second before you change your code scanf("%s", str); why str dont need &?, is it because this is a pointer to first element in array(?), im still very beginner is i use scanf("%s", str); is still ok? and

Comment: Your assumptions are correct @fiksx

Comment: But don't use `scanf`, you have an edit, use `fgets` and trim the trailing newline.

Comment: @KeineLust basically to make result not overlap need two pointer, first one all digits were removed and to looking for digit, while the second one showing the result? i still confuse about the purpose of second pointer. and also is it possible to declare char *str[100] in main?

Comment: No, you don't want an array of pointers, and you can print you array directly from main without using an extra pointer in the function if you prefer.

Comment: why cant i use scanf? im not quite understand how fgets works but from your code it use fgets for  standard input until it find the \n which is the enter key then it will asign \0 to ptr?? and  why need to use pointer?                                                                   if ((ptr = strchr(str, '\n'))) {
            *ptr = '\0';

Comment: @KeineLust if i want to use one pointer only, i just have to return str? and printf in main function?

Comment: Yo don't need to return str, it is already declared in main, scanf is dangerous in this case because you don't check bounds.

Comment: @KeineLust   okay but in "if ((ptr = strchr(str, '\n'))) { *ptr = '\0'; }" -> what the purpose of making pointer here? i know it change \n to \0? is this related to str?

Comment: here another way: https://paste.ubuntu.com/24689787/

Comment: @fiksx take a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787892/overflow-over-scanf8s-string