# Segmentation fault on ubuntu 23.04 scanf

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf, ubuntu-18.04, libc

This same code when I compile it using this command: `gcc chal.c -fno-pie -no-pie -fno-stack-protector -O0 -g -o chal`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char a[2];
    char b[8];

    scanf("%s", a);

    if(!memcmp(b, "chiching", 8)) {
        printf("Yes!");
        return 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I put input as `AAchiching`,
I get segmentation fault on Ubuntu 23.04 and I don't get segfault on Ubuntu 18.04. When I used gdb to follow along I have seen the segfault comes from scanf.

I want to know why is it like this?
Where can I study deep about it?

Comment: Your code contains [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), so anything can happen.

Comment: `AAchiching` doesn't fit in a `char a[2];`.

Comment: So you're trying to use a buffer overflow to fill in both variables?

Comment: Please see [Why doesn't my program crash when I write past the end of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452959/why-doesnt-my-program-crash-when-i-write-past-the-end-of-an-array)

Comment: %s is not valid on it's own in scanf, you have to use a width specifier

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yes My question was what changed in the latest Ubuntu 23.04. Did they change the scanf implementation? Was it some safety measures implemented on latest GCC? These very thing works on latest Arch. I have looked into it. But dk the best way to search what have been implemented on Ubuntu recently. And If there's a segfault there must be a reason behind these. There's no illegal memory access. It just tries to do this `test   al, 0xdb`.

Comment: I think the question is valid. The question maker knows that scanning more than the memory size is undefined behavior. The question, they want to ask is, where the implementation of "Segfault" insertion in case of memory overflow resides and how to learn more about it.

Comment: "There's no illegal memory access" - there is, argument to `scanf` needs to point to correctly allocated memory able to hold all input data. Then every question around "why this illegal code crashes with this settings, and doesn't crash with some other settings" is the same. Because the behaviour is undefined and therefore you cannot have any reasonable expectations. See also some questions about buffer overflow prevention: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787892/overflow-over-scanf8s-string